# Reading X509v3 extension fields from Request.ClientCertificate in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, x509certificate, pki

How do I read X509v3 extension fields from a certificate? I iterated through `AllKeys` in  `HttpClientCertificate` but that contains only the regular fields of the certificate & not the extension fields.

```
HttpClientCertificate cs = Request.ClientCertificate;
foreach (String s1 in cs.AllKeys)
    Response.Write( s1 + ":" + cs[s1] + "<br>");
```

So how do I read the extension fields?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation of [HttpClientCertificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpclientcertificate.aspx) and [X509Certificate2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx), it looks like you should be able to get a byte array of the entire certificate in ASN.1 format by using the [Certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpclientcertificate.certificate.aspx) property of `HttpClientCertificate`.  Then use this byte array to instantiate an `X509Certificate2` object through [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148413.aspx).

Once you have an `X509Certificate2` object, you can get the extensions through the [Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.extensions.aspx) property.  I'm not positive, but the extensions may also be listed when the [toString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148447.aspx) method is called on the `X509Certificate2` object.